# adding a third column to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jquery/javascript. I have the code below:

```
    var Tabs = {
    'tab1'  : 'string1',
    'tab2'  : 'string2',
    'tab3'  : 'string3'
    }

$.each(Tabs,function(i,j){      
var tmp = $('<li><a>'+i+'</a></li>');       
tmp.find('a').data('page',j);
})
```

I want my code to be something like this, but when I try it, it unfortunately doesnt work :

```
    var Tabs = {
    'tab1'  : 'string11' : 'string12',
    'tab2'  : 'string21': 'string22',
    'tab3'  : 'string31' : 'string32'
    }

$.each(Tabs,function(i,j,k){    
var tmp = $('<li><a class="'+k+'">'+i+'</a></li>');     
tmp.find('a').data('page',j);
})
```

In other words: I want to add a third parameter to the Tabs array. Can someone please explain to me what is the role of `:` .  Your usual help is alwys appreciated.

Comment: Every `Tabs` entry should become and array, e.g. `'tab1'  : ['string11', 'string12']`, you should then iterate over it.

Comment: Thank you moonwave99 for your help. It is okey

Comment: read up on javascript objects and arrays. Not hard to find lots of basic information

Comment: It’s [object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals). Note that the quotes aren’t strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you @rynah. That's what I was needing, these keywords as a js/jquery beginner

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl. But I think "object literal syntax" is a good keyword for a beginner in js/jquery, to look for docs.

Comment: You might want to read http://eloquentjavascript.net/.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you very much for the book I will certainly purshase it.

Comment: You can read it for free online or download it as HTML ;)

Comment: Yes I agree with you, I directly clicked on "get book" and it lead me to purshase page. Thank you for info @FelixKling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general pattern in JavaScript object literals is

```
var object = {
  key: value, 
  key: value
  // ...
};
```

So your object assignment is invalid. Furthermore, the callback passed to [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) only has two parameters: `index` and `value`. So you can not just use a third parameter there.

You could, however, use an array (or another object) as value like this:

```
var Tabs = {
    'tab1'  : ['string11', 'string12' ],
    'tab2'  : ['string21', 'string22' ],
    'tab3'  : ['string31', 'string32' ]
    }

$.each(Tabs,function(i,j){    
  var tmp = $('<li><a class="'+j[1]+'">'+i+'</a></li>');     
  tmp.find('a').data('page',j[0]);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from key:string to a key:object pair instead. Then you can have as many values as you want. It would be something like this:

```
var Tabs = {
    'tab1': {
        value1: 'string1',
        value2: 'string12'
    },
    'tab2': {
        value1: 'string2',
        value2: 'string22'
    },
    'tab3': {
        value1: 'string3',
        value2: 'string32'
    }
}
```